# NextJS: how to call function from within JSX to close modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm using the Tanstack React Query library to do a POST from a Modal which contains a form:

```
    const addDay = (day: TDay) => {
        const apiURL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL
        const queryURL = apiURL + router.asPath + '/days'

        console.log(queryURL)

        return axios.post<TDay>(queryURL, day, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                Accept: 'application/json',
            },
        })
    }

    const { mutate, isSuccess, isLoading, isError, error } = useMutation(addDay)

    const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        mutate(day)
    }
```

In my return JSX, I would like to close the Modal when I click Submit and it `isSuccess`. I'm trying to do it as:

```
return (
        <div>
            <Modal open={props.open}>
                <Modal.Header>Add Trip</Modal.Header>
                <label onClick={props.onClose}>
                    ✕
                </label>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <div>
                        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                            <...form fields...>
                            <Modal.Actions>
                                <div>
                                    {isLoading ? (
                                        <Button>Adding</Button>
                                    ) : (
                                        <>
                                            {isError ? (
                                                <h2>
                                                    An error occurred:
                                                    {error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error!'}
                                                </h2>
                                            ) : null}

                                            {isSuccess ? props.onClose : null}

                                            <Button>Submit</Button>
                                        </>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            </Modal.Actions>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    )
```

The main issue is in the `{isSuccess ? props.onClose : null}` where even if `isSuccess` is true, it's not calling props.onClose and closing the modal.

I know props.onClose works because I have an X button defined above as:

```
            <label onClick={props.onClose}>
                ✕
            </label>
```

And when I click it, it does close the modal.

How can I also call this function from within JSX so I can close the Modal when `isSuccess` is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way would be call on `onSuccess`.
According to there doc you can pass `onSuccess` function.

You can do something like this:

```
const onSuccess = (data) => {
  props.onClose()
}
const { mutate, isSuccess, isLoading, isError, error } = useMutation(addDay,{onSuccess})
```

doc reference: https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useMutation